# Dataframe specific transposition optimisation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to transpose a Pandas Dataframe from row to columns, where number of rows is dynamic. Then, transposed Dataframe must have dynamic number of columns also.

I succeeded using iterrows() and concat() methods, but I would like to optimize my code.

Please find my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
expected_results_transposed = pd.DataFrame()
for i, r in expected_results.iterrows():
    t = pd.Series([r.get('B')], name=r.get('A'))
    expected_results_transposed = pd.concat([expected_results_transposed, t], axis=1)
print("CURRENT CASE EXPECTED RESULTS TRANSPOSED:\n{0}\n".format(expected_results_transposed))
```

Please find an illustration of expected result :
[picture of expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSPga.png)

Do you have any solution to optimize my code using "standards" Pandas dataframes methods/options ?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) + [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
new_df=df.set_index('A').T.reset_index(drop=True)
new_df.columns.name=None
```

**Example**

```
  df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':'Mike Ana Jon Jenny'.split(),'B':[1,2,3,4]})
print(df2)

       A  B
0   Mike  1
1    Ana  2
2    Jon  3
3  Jenny  4
```

---

```
new_df=df2.set_index('A').T.reset_index(drop=True)
new_df.columns.name=None
print(new_df)

   Mike  Ana  Jon  Jenny
0     1    2    3      4
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to get "key" and "value" into the result dataset (please check the attached picture). How can we avoid them in the result ? NB : the goal is to concat this resulting dataframe with another one with same index (to avoid getting multiple rows but only 1)

Comment: He updated the solution. You can use reset index to reset the index. You can also remove the name of the columns using new_df-columns.name = None. Tell me if this solution is correct and if you can accept my answer. Thanks for the patience :)